# Sending data to Google App Engine/Datastore

Tags: php, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have an `Android app` a Simple form consist of some fields, I also have a `Web server using Google App` Engine in PHP. I was confused by This, should i send the Data from my Android app directly to my webserver, display the data in web server using local and then later on update thus data in datastore or should i send the data from my android app directly to the datastore and display in my webserver? I'm new with this Android and with this Google App Engine/Datastore, I hardly can't find proper Tutorials on Google App Engine using php. I think only few uses this thing.

Any Suggestion well do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical solution would be to provide an API for your app. I'm not familiar with PHP these days but there are bound to be plenty of REST frameworks that will take care of all the JSON conversion for you.

Your API (assuming it's PHP) can then take care of doing any necessary validation, authentication, performing queries, etc, against Datastore. [This](https://gae-php-tips.appspot.com/) may help.

If you're familiar with Java (you're writing an Android app) or Python, you can look at [Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/).

Comment: Sir is it posible to send data from Android to Webserver/Php and the Webserver will send to datastore?I'm confused with it. I have Read some tutorial about sending data to datastore but its Direct way. Ex. Android App to Datastore.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a PHP library to access Datastore from GAE, check this out:

https://github.com/tomwalder/php-gds

Comment: sir, what I understand is I should send data from my Android App to Datastore and then Using your PHP library to access/fetch thus data and view in my Webserver?

Comment: Yep, build an API wth PHP on App Engine

Comment: Sir is it possible to send thus data from android directly to Webserver/PHP library just for local use only?

Comment: The library works with the "development app server" which lets you work locally. You will have to sort out the networking so your simulator or local device can talk to your local dev server. But it is possible.

Comment: Sir, I will have to use your library where do I start? It's my first time to use PHP library

Comment: Hey there. The GitHub README has some good information https://github.com/tomwalder/php-gds

Comment: Sir after I download your library should I put it all in my project folder? I'm just confused about it.

Comment: You should use Composer for managing libraries and dependencies where possible

Comment: Sir if i download you library that came from the github and by that I will copy it into my project folder in Google App Engine. Is it still work?

Comment: Sir is this correct. Its my first time using composer in php
{
  "name": "tomwalder/php-gds",
  "description": "v2.1.0",
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "license": "proprietary",
  "require": {
    "tomwalder/php-appengine-search": "dev-master"
  },
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "author's name",
      "email": "email@example.com"
    }
  ]


}

Comment: It's pretty close. Your "name" field should be your project name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104507/discussion-between-junie-negentien-and-tom).

Comment: Sir, can I more about your Library in Chat?